# ¿Cómo ordenar arreglos guiándose por su id en JavaScript?

Tags: json, array, ordenamiento

Estoy tratando de hacer un método para poder ordenar varios arreglos solo con el `ID`. Les agradecería mucho si me pueden ayudar. Mil gracias.

```
$scope.route = [
    {title: 'new rute1', pos: [4.7923035, -75.67184388],  onRoute: true, id: 1},
    {title: 'new rute2', pos: [4.7925065, -75.67195166],  onRoute: true, id: 2},
    {title: 'new rute3', pos: [4.7925313, -75.67153209],  onRoute: true, id: 5},
    {title: 'new rute4', pos: [4.79248531, -75.67119606], onRoute: true, id: 4},
    {title: 'new rute5', pos: [4.79237921, -75.66942801], onRoute: true, id: 3}
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías ordenar haciendo uso del método [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) para ordenar los elementos en este caso por `id` pero si se desea por otra propiedad , se le modifica el `return`

```
array=  array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id-b.id; /* Modificar si se desea otra propiedad */
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias  Dev.Joel no sabia que había un método sort modifique un poco su codigo y me quedo de la siguiente forma $scope.ordenar = function(){
  $scope.route.sort(function (a, b) {
            console.log('a-->', a.id, 'b-->', b.id);
            return a.id - b.id;
        });

        console.log($scope.route);
}

Answer (score 0):

Una posible función que **devuelve un nuevo `Array`**, con el contenido ordenado por el campo `id`:

```
function OrdenarArray( arr ) {
  var tmp = [ ];

  arr.forEach( function( val ) { tmp[val.id] = val; } );

  return tmp;
}
```